# i want to download doc file and image from mysql database using jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, download

this is my code of view.jsp..

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File,java.util.*,java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
<html><body>
<h1> List of All Files to download </h1>
<%
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "root", "admin");
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from employeereg1");
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
%>
<table border=1>
<tr><td>Employee Name </td><td>Employee Address </td><td>Employee Resume </td><td>Employee Photo </td></tr>
<%
while(rs.next()){
%>
<tr>
<td><%=rs.getString(2)%> </td>
<td><%=rs.getString(3)%> </td>
<td><a href="Download.jsp?resumeId=<%=rs.getString(1)%>"> Download Here</a> </td>
<td><a href="Download.jsp?photoId=<%=rs.getString(1)%>"> Download Here</a> </td>
<%
}
%>
</table>
</body>
```

and this is download.jsp

```
<body>
<%
String fileName="";
String querytext="";
ServletOutputStream op1= null;
byte barray[] =null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "root", "admin");
if(request.getParameter("resumeId")!=null)
{
 querytext="select emp_resume from employeereg1 where emp_id="+request.getParameter("resumeId");
 }
 else{
 querytext="select emp_pic from employeereg1 where emp_id="+request.getParameter("photoId");    
 }
 PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(querytext);
 ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
 while(rs.next()) {
 fileName=rs.getString(1);
 }
 String mimetype=application.getMimeType(fileName);
 response.setContentType((mimetype != null) ? mimetype : "application/octet-stream");
 response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+fileName);
 Blob blb = rs.getBlob(1);
 byte[] bdata = blb.getBytes(1, (int) blb.length());
 OutputStream output =  response.getOutputStream();
 output.write(bdata);
 output.flush();
 output.close();
 %>
</body>
```

**this error will be shown**
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/DBFileDownload1] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /Download.jsp at line 63

60:     response.setContentType((mimetype != null) ? mimetype : "application/octet-stream");
61:     response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+fileName);
62:     // create the byte array from Blob
63:     Blob blb = rs.getBlob(1);
64:     byte[] bdata = blb.getBytes(1, (int) blb.length());
65: 
66:     // get the response Output stream object to write the content of the file into header

Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set`
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.checkRowPos(ResultSet.java:726)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getBlob(ResultSet.java:1416)
    at org.apache.jsp.Download_jsp._jspService(Download_jsp.java:157)

Comment: Don't use JSP for download, use [servlet](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-to-download-file-from-database).

Comment: why..? but image is display.